# Kohana 3 deployment controller problems

Tags: model-view-controller, deployment, controller, kohana-3

I have recently migrated my app from a windows localhost up to a linux host.

My problems is that I can't access a controller, I always keep getting the message: File not found.(From the web server)

And this is odd because the same code base is working on my localhost.

bootstrap.php:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)(/<param1>)(/<param2>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'index',
                  'param1' =>'',
                  'param2' =>'',
    ));
```

.htaccess:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /


# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

The odd thing that happens here is that if I go to :
www.myapp.com/ then the default controller executes and it finds the user/index function.

But if I manually write it as www.myapp.com/user/index I keep getting the File not found message.

I have tried renaming the controller files with lowercase so I guess thats not the problem, besides if that would be the problem, the default route wouldn`t find it in the first place, right?

If for example I write in the default route:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)(/<param1>)(/<param2>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'login',
                  'param1' =>'',
                  'param2' =>'',
    ));
```

And I accesss www.myapp.com , it would load the user function. I can't figure out what is wrong here, why when I write myapp.com/user/login it says file not found, but if I put it as the default route it opens it.

Answer (score 0):

did you set the base_url in bootstrap.php? if no, you should set the base_url  your_project_name/

if yes, you should set the RewriteBase /your_project_name/  also in your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in another thread related to this. You need to add this chunk of code into .htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
     </IfModule>
```

Hope it helps the others !